# Pull changes from github to local rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

So I know how to update the repository with my files (the master one at least).  And I know I can create a local branch with

```
$ git checkout -b [branch_name]
```

but that only creates it on the local git...how do i checkout a branch from the master on github and also overwrite files in my app directory, so I can update my project with the work of other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to ask, how to reset `master` on your local machine to that of the `master` on the origin?

If so:

Fetch all remote/origin changes and then hard reset your local `master` to `origin/master`'s head:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```